# Android Libgdx Memory Leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, libgdx, heap-memory

I am using libgdx and android studio to make a game. I have relatively little experience with either of these things. I believe that I have a memory leak somewhere induced by graphics, but I'm not sure as i know that libgdx reserves a large amount of heap space. The MAT analysis says:

```
The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 17,790,184 (31.63%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.util.LongSparseArray[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

19 instances of "java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod[]", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 11,902,776 (21.16%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:
•java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod[64707] @ 0x70b7e4b0 - 3,894,624 (6.92%) bytes. 
•java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod[52675] @ 0x70be6888 - 3,061,192 (5.44%) bytes. 
•java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod[21833] @ 0x70000ac0 - 1,336,112 (2.38%) bytes. 
•java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod[14651] @ 0x771d2d60 - 966,680 (1.72%) bytes. 
•java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod[11453] @ 0x71f964e0 - 806,432 (1.43%) bytes. 
•java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod[11047] @ 0x709b39d8 - 662,680 (1.18%) bytes. 

205 instances of "android.graphics.NinePatch", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 10,041,968 (17.86%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.lang.Object[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"

Keywords
java.lang.Object[]
android.graphics.NinePatch

32 instances of "java.lang.DexCache", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 6,358,016 (11.31%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:
•java.lang.DexCache @ 0x70b50608 - 1,262,528 (2.24%) bytes. 
•java.lang.DexCache @ 0x71d2f870 - 1,177,232 (2.09%) bytes. 
•java.lang.DexCache @ 0x70bc4b60 - 903,320 (1.61%) bytes. 
•java.lang.DexCache @ 0x72178f80 - 636,768 (1.13%) bytes. 
•java.lang.DexCache @ 0x723d13f0 - 633,088 (1.13%) bytes.
```

If my code is needed, I can supply it, but I'm not sure which part to provide, as I'm not sure where the leak is. I greatly appreciate any advice

Answer (score 0):

GC behavior changes with the GC policy for example if the policy is for maximum throughput then the JVM will allocate objects till it reaches Xmx. When it reaches threshold the GC will kick in to clear the dead object. If the GC policy is for less pause time a)Scavenge GC and b) Global Gc occurs  until Global GC occurs we can't ensure whether Dead objects are cleared.

It is better to collect logs on OOM which means GC tries as much it could to clear the dead objects and then JVM throws OOM error. If you run MAT on the heap dump at this  point you could find the leak suspects appropriately.

For further information on who is holding the strong references on the leaking objects write OQL like this select * from "packagename.classname" After executing right click on the objects->Path to GC roots-> Exclude soft/Weak/Phantom references. On doing this MAT will give information on who is holding the reference still because of which GC did not clear the objects.

Comment: Verbose gc logs will also helps in identifying leak.

Comment: Verbose logs o n GCMV helps in identifying the allocation pattern but actual suspect  could be find  through heapdump and using the above mechanism.